# Bloc provider error in the GoRouter redirect function when using context.push from an onPressed event

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-go-router

I was trying to make my router the one responsible for the redirection logic whenever the authentication status of my AuthCubit changes.
I tried to use the `refreshListener` property of my GoRouter but I read that it's being deprecated and that the proper way would be to listen to my cubit from the `redirect` function.
While it's correctly working , I'm getting the following error when I change the screen from the onPressed of a button:

```
Exception has occurred.
_AssertionError ('package:provider/src/provider.dart': Failed assertion: line 274 pos 7: 'context.owner!.debugBuilding ||
          listen == false ||
          debugIsInInheritedProviderUpdate': Tried to listen to a value exposed with provider, from outside of the widget tree.

This is likely caused by an event handler (like a button's onPressed) that called
Provider.of without passing `listen: false`.

To fix, write:
Provider.of<AuthCubit>(context, listen: false);

It is unsupported because may pointlessly rebuild the widget associated to the
event handler, when the widget tree doesn't care about the value.

The context used was: Router<Object>(dependencies: [UnmanagedRestorationScope, _InheritedProviderScope<AuthCubit?>], state: _RouterState<Object>#c6a43)
)
```

And this is the stacktrace:

```
flutter: Register buttonn pressed
flutter: #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:51:61)
#1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:40:5)
#2      Provider.of (package:provider/src/provider.dart:274:7)
#3      WatchContext.watch (package:provider/src/provider.dart:693:21)
#4      appRouter.<anonymous closure> (package:teslo_shop/config/router/app_router.dart:35:33)
#5      RouteConfiguration.redirect.processRedirect (package:go_router/src/configuration.dart:417:80)
#6      RouteConfiguration.redirect (package:go_router/src/configuration.dart:429:14)
#7      GoRouteInformationParser._redirect (package:go_router/src/parser.dart:156:10)
#8      GoRouteInformationParser.parseRouteInformationWithDependencies (package:go_router/src/parser.dart:97:32)
#9      _RouterState._processRouteInformation (package:flutter/src/widgets/router.dart:741:8)
#10     _RouterState._handleRouteInformationProviderNotification (package:flutter/src/widgets/router.dart:759:5)
#11     ChangeNotifier.notifyListeners (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:433:24)
#12     GoRouteInformationProvider.notifyListeners (package:go_router/src/information_provider.dart:144:11)
#13     GoRouteInformationProvider._setValue (package:go_router/src/information_provider.dart:152:7)
#14     GoRouteInformationProvider.go (package:go_router/src/information_provider.dart:174:5)
#15     GoRouter.go (package:go_router/src/router.dart:340:30)
#16     GoRouterHelper.go (package:go_router/src/misc/extensions.dart:25:25)
#17     _LoginForm.build.<anonymous closure> (package:teslo_shop/features/auth/presentation/screens/login_screen.dart:129:37)
#18     _InkResponseState.handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1183:21)
#19     GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:275:24)
#20     TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:652:11)
#21     BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:309:5)
#22     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:279:7)
#23     GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:167:27)
#24     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:492:20)
#25     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:468:22)
#26     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:439:11)
#27     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:413:7)
#28     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:376:5)
#29     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:323:7)
#30     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:292:9)
#31     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:328:13)
#32     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:410:7)
#33     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:262:31)
```

My login screen, which is where the user is redirected initially:

```
class _LoginForm extends StatelessWidget {
  const _LoginForm();

  void showSnackbar(BuildContext context, String message) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
        .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(message)));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final textStyles = Theme.of(context).textTheme;
    BlocListener<AuthCubit, AuthState>(
      listener: (context, state) {},
    );

    return Center(
      child: BlocListener<AuthCubit, AuthState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          if (state.errorMessage == null) {
            return;
          }
          showSnackbar(context, state.errorMessage!);
        },
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const SizedBox(height: 50),
              Text('Login', style: textStyles.titleLarge),
              const SizedBox(height: 90),
              BlocBuilder<LoginFormCubit, LoginFormState>(
                builder: (context, state) {
                  return CustomTextFormField(
                    label: 'Correo',
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    errorMessage: state.status == Status.isFormPosted
                        ? state.email.errorMessage
                        : null,
                    onChanged: context.read<LoginFormCubit>().onEmailChanged,
                  );
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 30),
              BlocBuilder<LoginFormCubit, LoginFormState>(
                builder: (context, state) {
                  return CustomTextFormField(
                    label: 'Contraseña',
                    obscureText: true,
                    errorMessage: state.status == Status.isFormPosted
                        ? state.password.errorMessage
                        : null,
                    onChanged: context.read<LoginFormCubit>().onPasswordChanged,
                  );
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 30),
              SizedBox(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 60,
                  child: CustomFilledButton(
                    text: 'Ingresar',
                    buttonColor: Colors.black,
                    onPressed: () {
                      final Function(
                              {required String email, required String password})
                          submitCallback = context.read<AuthCubit>().loginUser;
                      context.read<LoginFormCubit>().onSubmit(submitCallback);
                    },
                  )),
              const Spacer(flex: 2),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  const Text('¿No tienes cuenta?'),
                  TextButton(
                      onPressed: () => {
                            print('Register buttonn pressed'),
                            context.go('/register')
                          },
                      child: const Text('Crea una aquí'))
                ],
              ),
              const Spacer(flex: 1),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the line from my Login screen that changes the route:

```
                  TextButton(
                      onPressed: () => context.push('/register'),
                      child: const Text('Crea una cuenta aquí'))
```

Seems like when I press this button, the resulting widget isn't in the widget tree

This is my router code:

```
final appRouter = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/splash',
  routes: [
    ///* Auth Routes
    GoRoute(
      path: '/splash',
      builder: (context, state) => const CheckAuthStatusScreen(),
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/login',
      builder: (context, state) => const LoginScreen(),
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/register',
      builder: (context, state) => const RegisterScreen(),
    ),

    ///* Product Routes
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (context, state) => const ProductsScreen(),
    ),
  ],
  redirect: (context, state) {
    final authState = context.watch<AuthCubit>().state;
    final goingTo = state.matchedLocation;
    switch (authState.authStatus) {
      case AuthStatus.checking:
        return '/splash';
      case AuthStatus.authenticated:
        if (goingTo == '/register' ||
            goingTo == '/login' ||
            goingTo == '/splash') {
          return '/';
        }
        return null;
      case AuthStatus.unauthenticated:
        if (goingTo == '/register') return null;
        return '/login';
    }
  },
);
```

The `final authState = context.watch<AuthCubit>().state;`  line is where the error raises after I press the TextButton.

And here are the code blocks for my AuthCubit and its AuthState, though I don't think they are the problem

```
class AuthCubit extends Cubit<AuthState> {
  final AuthRepository authRepository;
  final KeyValueStorageService keyValueStorageService;
  AuthCubit(
      {required this.authRepository, required this.keyValueStorageService})
      : super(const AuthState());

  Future<void> loginUser(
      {required String email, required String password}) async {
    emit(state.copyWith(authStatus: AuthStatus.checking));
    try {
      final User user =
          await authRepository.login(email: email, password: password);
      _setLoggedUser(user);
    } on WrongCredentials {
      logout('Usuario o contraseña incorrectos');
    } on ConnectionTimeout {
      logout('Connection timeout');
    } catch (e) {
      logout('Error desconocido');
    }
  }

  void registerUser({required String email, required String password}) {}
  Future<void> checkAuthStatus() async {
    final token = await keyValueStorageService.getValue<String>('token');
    if (token == null) {
      logout('Error de autenticación, ingrese de nuevo');
    }
    try {
      authRepository.checkAuthStatus(token: token!);
    } catch (error) {
      logout('Error de autenticación, ingrese de nuevo');
    }
  }

  Future<void> _setLoggedUser(User user) async {
    await keyValueStorageService.setKeyValue('token', user.token);
    emit(AuthState(user: user, authStatus: AuthStatus.authenticated));
  }

  Future<void> logout([String? errorMessage]) async {
    await keyValueStorageService.removeKeyValue('token');
    emit(
      AuthState(
          authStatus: AuthStatus.unauthenticated, errorMessage: errorMessage),
    );
  }
}
```

```
enum AuthStatus { checking, authenticated, unauthenticated }

class AuthState {
  final AuthStatus authStatus;
  final User? user;
  final String? errorMessage;

  const AuthState(
      {this.authStatus = AuthStatus.unauthenticated,
      this.user,
      this.errorMessage});

  AuthState copyWith({
    AuthStatus? authStatus,
    User? user,
    String? errorMessage,
  }) {
    return AuthState(
      authStatus: authStatus ?? this.authStatus,
      user: user ?? this.user,
      errorMessage: errorMessage ?? this.errorMessage,
    );
  }

  @override
  String toString() =>
      'AuthState(authStatus: $authStatus, user: $user, errorMessage: $errorMessage)';
}
```

First thing i tried was to follow the erorr's advice, changing the `context.watch` to either:
`final authState = context.read<AuthCubit>().state;` or `final authState = BlocProvider.of<AuthCubit>(context, listen: false).state;`, which i belive are equivalent.

This fixes the error but the redirect doesn't get called whenever the state changes, which is what I need. So it's not actually a solution.

I also tried to use `context.go` instead of `context.push` in my button, thinking that maybe that way the resulting screen would not be outside of the widget tree, but that didn't work.

Lastly, if I wrap my `redirect` code in a `try catch` block, it catches the error and, strangely, the redirection works (as if it was being called two times in a row, the second execution working properly). But there's still an error there and I feel this might happen only in development, so I can't leave it like that.

Am I missing something here? Is there a way to avoid the screen rendered after the onPressed being outside the widget tree? Or maybe this is the wrong aproach? I've seen a copule of different aproaches but usually these involve rendering some kind of intermediate screen anytime the route changes, causing kind of a small flickering that makes the UX worse.